# What methods can be used to prevent the browser (IE11 specifically) from storing credentials / autocomplete

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, html

Going through Pen Test and it was asked of us to disable auto complete in our CC payment fields.

We tried adding `autocomplete=off` and also tried `false` on the input filed. A
ny suggestions to override this 'feature' in IE11 and other browser specific extensions?

Comment: are you sure that it's the browser filling in the values and not a plugin (LastPass, etc.)?

Comment: Is the field type text, or password?

Comment: @sara please add some more details, is possible add the html snippet of the changes you made as that can be relevant to providing an answer.

Comment: As of Chrome 34, the Chrome browser will ignore the `autocomplete=off` directive: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/04/09/chrome_makes_new_password_grab_in_version_34/

Answer (score 1):

It is true that most major browsers now ignore the autocomplete value if set in the web application.  However, IE11 only ignores this setting on password fields, it should still honour the autocomplete setting on CC fields.  As Xander suggested, it could be worth checking the input type for your CC payment field.